# Best way to do a database object search for a few thousand search terms

Tags: sql, sql-server

I’m trying to see if there’s a way to write a query to search the SQL Server database for particular terms (terms that would be found in a stored procedure).

Ideally, I would like to have the results to show the (1) search term and (2) the stored procedure that contains the term (NULL value if not found).

I know how to do a database search:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       o.name AS Object_Name,
       o.type_desc
  FROM sys.sql_modules m
       INNER JOIN
       sys.objects o
         ON m.object_id = o.object_id
 WHERE m.definition Like '%[ABD]%’
```

The problem would be getting the few thousand search terms I need to make appear as a field (in the select statement) and how to most efficiently do a LIKE search with so many search terms.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: There is no real efficient way to do this in T-SQL using `LIKE`; no matter how you slice it it's going to do a few thousand individual string comparisons. The comparison itself is easily achieved by sticking the terms in a table and doing a `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Terms WHERE m.definition LIKE '%' + Terms.Pattern + '%')`. It probably won't be fast, but I would guess this is a one-off and not something you do a lot. If it *is* something you do a lot, extracting the DB definition in a script and using traditional full-text indexing would be better.

Comment: Are you doing this to find anything that references certain objects? If so, there are DMVs that will probably be more efficient than a search through object definitions.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I created a new table with a column that has all the search terms. Here’s the issue I have. How would I be able to show every value from the table and then show whether or not a search result was found. 

I can’t quite figure it out since I can’t join the table I created with the search terms to sys.sql_modules or sys.objects. 

Ideally, I’d every search term (from the table I created) to show in the results, as well as another column showing if there was a search hit or not. 

Any ideas?